# Show that a certain element is a linear combination of tensors

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, bialgebras

I posted this question on MSE but got no answer even after putting a bounty on it, so I figured I can try to ask here.

Let $(A, \Delta: A \to A \otimes A)$ be bialgebra (unital and counital) such that the map
$$T: A \otimes A \to A \otimes A: a \otimes b \mapsto \Delta(a)(1 \otimes b)$$
is surjective.

We write $\Delta(a) = a_{(1)}\otimes a_{(2)}$ (Hopf-Sweedler notation). Is it true that
we can write an element $x \otimes y \otimes 1$ as a linear combination of elements of the form
$$a_{(1)}\otimes b_{(1)}\otimes a_{(2)}b_{(2)} c$$
where $a,b,c \in A$?

**My attempt**: I believe so. We can write
$$x \otimes 1 = \sum a_{(1)}\otimes a_{(2)}b$$
(the summation depending on $a,b$).
Hence,
$$x \otimes y \otimes 1 = \sum a_{(1)}\otimes y \otimes a_{(2)}b= \sum (a_{(1)}\otimes 1 \otimes a_{(2)})(1 \otimes y \otimes b)$$
and we then write $y \otimes b = \sum b_{(1)}\otimes b_{(2)}c$
and we and up with something like
$$x \otimes y \otimes 1 = \sum \sum a_{(1)}\otimes b_{(1)}\otimes a_{(2)}b_{(2)}c$$

I know I was not very careful with the summations, and some sums are depending on others, but I wanted to check if my idea was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your argument shows that there exist $a,b,c$ with $$\Delta(a) = \sum_i a^i_{(1)} \otimes a^i_{(2)}$$
$$\Delta(b) = \sum_j b^j_{(1)} \otimes b^j_{(2)}$$

$$x \otimes y \otimes 1 = \sum_i \sum_j a_{(1)}^i \otimes b_{(1)}^i \otimes a_{(2) }^ib_{(2)}^jc $$

I don't really understand your notation but I think this is what you want to prove.

The proof you give is exactly correct, the point being that $y$ and $b$ don't depend on $i$ and thus it's not true that "some sums are depending on others".

A possible point of confusion is that the letter $b$ refers to two different things (it changes in the middle of the equation $y \otimes b = \sum b_{(1)} \otimes b_{(2)}c$).